Certbot failed to authenticate some domains on AWS EB Linux 2023 (single instance)
I have a .NET website that I published to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It is a single instance, .NET Core on Linux 2023. I SSH to the EC2 instance and installed certbot.
When I run:
certbot certonly

I get:
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain example.com
Challenge failed for domain www.example.com
http-01 challenge for example.com
http-01 challenge for www.example.com

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: example.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 44.223.223.199: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/fS2LXXl8MNia09szGIDTQx-pBi-oX6WFR7to1_vyTx4: 404

  Domain: www.example.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 44.223.223.199: Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/-3d4YoMIACMLV_pZ9EAJzYK5iznPWuYQA7SelMnV1a0: 404


You are trying to get a certificate for www.example.com. Follow the instructions here and instead attempt to acquire a cert for a domain you own: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-certbot-standalone-mode-to-retrieve-let-s-encrypt-ssl-certificates-on-ubuntu-16-04

Thanks for the info. That is what I did (although the instructions you show are for ubuntu) but it does not work for Linux 2023 single instance.
